# Find function $f(x)$ such that $f'(-1)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f''(-1)>0,f''(0)<0,f''(1)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Find  function $f(x)$ such that $$f'(-1)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$$ and $$f''(-1)>0,f''(0)<0,f''(1)>0$$.

Can anyone explain how to answer the above question? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can start by drawing a graph. Plot the points $x=-1,0,1$. You know your function has zero derivative at those points, and that the derivative is increasing, decreasing and increasing respectively. For example, since the derivative is increasing from -1 to 0, and since $f'(-1)=0$, that means the derivative will be positive, hence the function is increasing on $[-1,0]$. So start drawing some curves that satisfy this, keeping in mind you have freedom to choose the values $f(-1),f(0),f(1)$.

Comment: Your function must have a relative minimum at -1 and 1 and a relative maximum at 0.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural way to do this would be by searching for a polynomial having $-1,0,1$ as its roots. The simplest of such polynomials is: $P(x) = x(x-1)(x+1)$. We have that $P'(x) = 3x^2 - 1$. Thus, fortunately, $f(x) = \int_0^x P(t) dt$ satisfies the requirement.

Comment: A simple trig function will do this without all the algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Play around with $\cos (ax)$ for some constant $a.$